# Little problem with sliding panel in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

When i open the info slide the panel ads a margin.. how can i fix it.. the problem ocurs only in IE (IE tab plugin for firefox) and in IE7 and IE8 the tooltip is not showing.. Thank you very much. [Link](http://www.pocetna.net) to site

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a version of your code that shows the problem. 
IE's way is usually to freely accept illegal text (XML and CSS). So I recommend that you first test in firefox or chrome.

Use pastebin or jsbin to share your code and css